# Android Application run perfectly on emulator but crash on my own mobile

Tags: android, list, contacts

i made an Android Application who create a list with the email of all contacts and when you click on a contact send the email to him.

The problem is that when the app has to receive the list of contacts, crash on my mobile but works perfectly on the ADV of eclipse.

Main Class:

```
package com.example.mail;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

public static final int R_CODE_CONTACT_LIST =10;

Intent intent;
EditText txtTo,txtSubject,txtMsg;
ImageButton btnSend,btnContacts;    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    txtTo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtto);
    txtSubject=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtsubject);
    txtMsg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtmessage);
    btnSend=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
    btnContacts=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btncontacts);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnContacts.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()){

    case R.id.btnsend:
        if (allTextWritten()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); // it's not ACTION_SEND
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, txtSubject.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtMsg.getText().toString());
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"+txtTo.getText().toString())); // or just "mailto:" for blank
            //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // this will make such that when user returns to your app, your app is displayed, instead of the email app.
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else{
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please, fill all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        break;
    case R.id.btncontacts:
        intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,ContactsList.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,R_CODE_CONTACT_LIST);
        break;
    }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try{
        Log.d("request",""+requestCode);
        Log.d("result",""+resultCode);
        if (requestCode==R_CODE_CONTACT_LIST)
          txtTo.setText(data.getStringExtra("email"));
        else
          txtTo.setText("");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        //Toast.makeText(this, "list closed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //Control line
    }

}



private boolean allTextWritten(){
    boolean isWritten=true;
    //if all text boxes are filled returns true 
    return isWritten & !("".equals(txtTo.getText().toString()))
                     &     !("".equals(txtSubject.getText().toString()))
                     & !("".equals(txtMsg.getText().toString()));       
}

}
```

List Class:

```
package com.example.mail;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class ContactsList extends ListActivity {
private final int   REQUEST_CODE=10;
//private final int     FAIL_CODE=-1;
private boolean destroy=true;

protected ArrayList<String> contactList =new ArrayList<String>();
protected ArrayList<String> mail =new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);
    getContactEmails(this);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactList));
}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (destroy){
        Log.d("destroy",""+destroy);
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("email","");
        setResult(REQUEST_CODE,intent);
        destroy=false;
    }
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("email",mail.get(position));
    setResult(REQUEST_CODE,intent);
    destroy=false;
    finish();
   }

private void getContactEmails(Context context) {
    String emailIdOfContact = null;
    int emailType = Email.TYPE_WORK;
    String contactName = null;

        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                int newMail=1;
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                contactName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                // Log.d("mail","....contact name....." +contactName);
                cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
                while (emails.moveToNext()) {
                    String multiMail="";
                    emailIdOfContact = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
                    if (newMail!=1)
                        multiMail=""+newMail;
                    contactList.add(contactName+multiMail+" - "+emailIdOfContact.substring(0,10)+"...");
                    mail.add(emailIdOfContact);
                    // Log.d("mail","...COntact Name ...." + contactName + "...contact Number..."+ emailIdOfContact);
                    emailType = emails.getInt(emails.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                    newMail++;

                }
                emails.close();

            }
        }// end of contact name cursor
        cur.close();
}

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mail"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mail.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.mail.ContactsList"
        android:theme="@style/GeneralBackgroudStyle"/>
</application>
```

Someone has any idea? Thanks all.

---

**Edit** Logcat Exception:

```
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mail/com.example.mail.ContactsList}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1651)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at com.example.mail.ContactsList.getContactEmails(ContactsList.java:82)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at com.example.mail.ContactsList.onCreate(ContactsList.java:34)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-09 09:47:06.340: E/AndroidRuntime(18915):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is the exception listed in the logcat when it crashes on your device?

Comment: is your phone's OS an earlier version than the one you're developing with?

Comment: Jeff, no, i am developing the app for 2.2 and my phone is 2.3

Comment: did you remove the phone app previously ?

Comment: Foamy: the application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. Im running it on my mobile phone. so there isnt logcat

Comment: Arnaldo: no, is a new one. i installed it this morning.

Comment: You can get logcat from the phone, if the phone is connected to your computer and adb can find it.  You would have an easier time debugging if you were looking at the logcat on the phone.

Comment: I'm trying to download the drivers for my phone for connect it to Eclipse

Comment: ok i got the logcat exception: dexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: is it dexOutOfBoundsException or indexOutOfBoundsException? Doesnt it shows which like the problem is happening? Can you paste the complete stack trace.

Comment: the complete stack is now on the post

Comment: emailIdOfContact might be less than 10 chars, And you are calling substring(0,10) on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
contactList.add(contactName+multiMail+" - "+emailIdOfContact.substring(0,10)+"...");
```

The exception occurs on the substring() call. Since you hardcoded the values, I assume that `emailIdOfContact` is shorter than 10 characters, thus the error. Did you really want to hardcode this without checking beforehand? You may have working strings in the emulator, but not on your actual phone.

Comment: really thanks :) I never thought that the email could be empty in the contact list.

that was the problem, because its very extrange to have an email less than 10 characters

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem:

Upon returning via onActivity Result:

- On phone: ArrayList data was lost and ArrayList.size always was 0;
- Emulator: ArrayList data was present and normal

Declared the array as a static synchronizedList, now it works on both phone and emulator.

use this.....

private static List array_list_name = Collections.synchronizedList( new ArrayList())

officialDocs: [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)